# how to store app value in mvc

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4

In my project I need some data in all of project to show the user .

Let me to Explain .

For Example : `Site Title` , `Logo` , `Tel` , `Email` , `Fax` , and some setting like as Background color  ,....

to do this I use a static Class with some static Property like this :

```
 public static class SysInfo {
    public static SystemInformation SystemInformationModel {
        get;
        set;
    }
    static SystemInfo() {
        SystemInformationModel = new SysInfoService(uow).Get();
    }

    public static string Tel {
        get {
            return SystemInformationModel.Tel;
        }
    }
    public static string Email {
        get {
            return SystemInformationModel.Email;
        }
    }
 }
```

this code is a bag . when User Visit my site and tel is `123` and Manager Site Change Tel in Admin to `1234` . when User Refersh site he see last Tel Value and it does not change to `1234` because My call This class On time of BeginRequest .

what is the best way to do this ?

Comment: Simply your property is static so the data it holds would be shared all over the application so when Manager Site change tel in Admin, you should also update those values in static property and as you mentioned they all are static user will automatically get the updated values that's it..! :)

Comment: Change your properties to read from Asp.net cache instead of storing the value in a backing field. You can add the values to the cache with specific expirations (every minute for example) or even every 5 seconds. If cache does not contain the value, read and put it again. (Synchronize access to the reloading operation)

Answer (score 0):

As you mentioned, you used static class for this purpose, so as you know static classes are shared and would be changed until the app is alive in memory.

So I can say you should add a setter method for your static class and after changing a value by the manager, call this method to change your values in this class.